A maximum principle for a linear operator with singular term
It is well know that if $\Omega$ is a smooth boundend domain in $\mathbb{R}^N$ and if we have
$$\mathcal{L} u = -\Delta u + c(x) u$$
with $c(x) \ge 0$ in $\Omega$ and $c \in L^\infty(\Omega)$ (or $C^{0,\alpha}(\overline{\Omega})$), then $\mathcal{L}$ satisfies the strong maximum principle, i.e., if $u \in C^2(\Omega) \cap C(\overline{\Omega})$ is non-negative and it satisfies
$$
\begin{cases} \mathcal{L}u \ge 0, \quad x \in \Omega \\
u = 0, \quad x \in \partial \Omega \end{cases},
$$
then $u > 0$ in $\Omega$ and $\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial \nu} <0 $ on $\partial \Omega$.
My question is: There is a version of the SMP when $c$ it is not bounded? For instance, I'm working with the operator
$$
Lu = -\Delta u + \dfrac{|\nabla v(x)|}{v(x)} u
$$
where $v \in C^2_0(\overline{\Omega})$ and $v\ge0$ in $\Omega$. Since $v$ may vanish, the map $x \mapsto c(x) = \dfrac{|\nabla v(x)|}{v(x)}$ may not be bounded.
Any  help is very appreciated.

I don't see how $c$ is well-defined. Or do you set $c(x) = 0$, when $v(x) = 0$?

Haven't tried it, but maybe Stampacchia's truncation method (Brézis, Functional Analysis, Section 9.7) might help
